# Медиана целочисленного потока

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Рассмотрим картинку, из которой станет понятно, как находить медиану целочисленного потока:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мы видим, для нахождения медианы удобно разбить поток на две части: В левой части находится почти половина элементов в отсортированном порядке, аналогично - в правой. Обе части вместе образуют отсортированный массив: слева меньшие элементы, справа большие.

Медиана вычисляется так: если количество элементов слева и справа равно, - медиана равна среднему значению максимума слева и минимума справа (см. картинки). Если слева на один элемент больше (справа больше не бывает), тогда медиана равна максимуму слева.

Задачу удобно решить при помощи максимальной и минимальной кучи. Мое решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>

using std::priority_queue;
using std::vector;
using std::greater;
using std::less;


// Балансирование размеров куч. Если размеры отличаются на 2,
// перекидываем элемент из одной кучи в другую
void balance_heaps(priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>>& min, priority_queue<int>& max)
{
    if(max.size() - min.size() == 2)
    {
        min.push(max.top());
        max.pop();
    }
    if((min.size() - max.size()) == 2)
    {
        max.push(min.top());
        min.pop();
    }
}

// Прочитанный из входного потока элемент добавляется в одну из двух куч.
// При этом производится балансирование размеров
void push_new_value(priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>>& min, priority_queue<int>& max, int value)
{
    max.push(value);
    balance_heaps(min, max);
}

// Вычисление медианы среди всех элементов.
// Если число элементов четное, медиана вычисляется как средне арифметическое
// двух центральных элементов в упорядоченной последовательности
double find_median(priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>>& min, priority_queue<int>& max)
{
    if (min.size() == max.size())
        return (max.top() + min.top()) / 2.0;
    else
        return double(max.top());
}

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int> max_heap;
    std::priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> min_heap;

    int value;
    while(std::cin >> value)
    {
        push_new_value(min_heap, max_heap, value);
        std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << find_median(min_heap, max_heap) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Алгоритм работает так: новые значения добавляем только в максимальную кучу. Допустимо, когда количество элементов в `max`-куче на один больше, чем в `min`-куче. Если слева на два элемента больше, - кучи надо балансировать перекладыванием лишнего элемента в меньшую по размеру кучу.

Мой алгоритм вычисляет медиану как будто правильно, когда число элементов четное или равно единице, но в остальных случаях он дает неверный результат. Где я ошибся? Алгоритм настолько прозрачный, что я не вижу, где ошибка.

Пытался изменять алгоритм, но фиксы типа этих оказывались тождественными преобразованиями говнокода. Ничего не поломалось, но и результат тот же.

```
// Прочитанный из входного потока элемент добавляется в одну из двух куч.
// При этом производится балансирование размеров
void push_new_value(priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>>& min, priority_queue<int>& max, int value)
{
    if(max.empty())
        max.push(value);
    else{
        if(value >= max.top())
            max.push(value);
        else
            min.push(value);
    }
    balance_heaps(min, max);
}

// Вычисление медианы среди всех элементов.
// Если число элементов четное, медиана вычисляется как средне арифметическое
// двух центральных элементов в упорядоченной последовательности
double find_median(priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>>& min, priority_queue<int>& max)
{
    if (min.size() == max.size())
        return (max.top() + min.top()) / 2.0;
    else if(max.size() > min.size())
        return max.top();
    else
        return min.top();
}
```

Comment: а в каком случае может выполняться `(min.size() - max.size()) == 2`?

Comment: Когда в min-куче на 2 элемента больше, чем в max-куче. Хотя, похоже, это условие не будет выполняться. Элементы поступают в max-кучу, и если их там на 2 больше, один сбрасывается в min-кучу. В min-куче переполнения не будет. Что тогда делать?

Comment: вообще, я думаю балансировку стоит делать только если в максимальной очереди - больше элементов чем в минимальной, то есть. положили в макс, если количество элементов одинаковое - все хорошо, если нет - переносится элемент из макс в мин

Comment: тогда все сходится с описанием в части _Если слева элементов на 1 больше (**справа больше не бывает**)_

Comment: Тогда балансировка будет происходить даже если в max-куче на 1 элемент больше. Но этот случай допустим: тогда этот один элемент будет центральным в отсортированной последовательности - медианой.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите, пусть вы добавляете числа 1,2,3

После 1 - оно в `max_heap`. 2 добавляется в него же, но балансируется в `min_heap`. Медиана - 1.5, OK.

Добавим 3 - оно идет в `max_heap`, **нарушая** условие, что все элементы справа больше всех слева. И получается, что у вас медиана для 1 2 3 - 3... Т.е. по сути вы нарушаете **инвариант алгоритма**.

Я бы, наверное, "симметризовал" очереди, и смотрел, куда добавлять - влево или вправо...

Comment: Мое исправленное решение с выбором подходящей кучи для очередного числа точно так же не работает. https://ideone.com/WKvtSb   Немного поправил выбор кучи: https://ideone.com/papgI4  Как будто стало лучше. Сейчас проверю алгоритм на сайте с этой задачей.

Comment: Ура, принялось! А как можно было бы спроектировать класс более профессионально? Для начала я подумал о том, чтобы в нем использовался произвольный тип.

Comment: А так? https://ideone.com/1N7KIp А, вы уже нашли эту ошибку :)